# How to open Different URLs(with different usernames and passwords) in Selenium

Tags: java, excel, selenium, data-driven-tests

I have successfully read data from an Excel file , consisting of three columns(URL/FQDN , username , password).
This Excel Sheet consists of FQDNs of various servers of mine. I have another function that needs to perform certain task on all of these servers.
Since I am very new to Selenium/java , I would appreciate any help regarding the fact on how I can open all the url's on different browser windows , and pass username and password for each one of them. And later on I can try to manage the task/same action which I need to perform on all of them
Here's the piece of code I have written so far to read Excel Sheet-:

public class modif {

```
public static FileInputStream fis;
public static XSSFWorkbook wb;
public static XSSFSheet sheet;
public static String row;
public static XSSFCell cell;



public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try {
        getCellData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static void getCellData() throws IOException
{
    fis=new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\windows\\Desktop\\hostname.xlsx");
    wb=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    sheet=wb.getSheet("hostname");

    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum()-sheet.getFirstRowNum();

    //Create a loop over all the rows of excel file to read it

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount+1; i++) {
        
        

        Row row = sheet.getRow(i);

        //Create a loop to print cell values in a row

        for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {

            //Print Excel data in console

            System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue() + " ");
            
            
            
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

first of all look at the access modifiers of your functions (always very important!). Functions that you only use in a single class should always be private.

What you want to do is actually not that hard to achieve. Just write a (private) function that you give 3 parameters: url, username and password. You will call this function within your for loop of the getCellData() function. On how you exactly start a new window (or tab which i think would be better imo), should be pretty straight forward. I would have to google to! Just import the Selenium WebDriver lib, and then read into it! There are plenty of funtions to assist in what you want to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `getCellData()` at least return a list of URL for this instance.

Once it gets executed you would have something like this :

**Code :**

```
public String[] getCellData() {
        return new String[]{"https://www.google.co.in", "https://www.youtube.com", "https://stackoverflow.com"};
    }
```

To open every URL in new tab :

```
@Test
public void testSO() throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        String[] allUrls = getCellData();
        System.out.println(allUrls.length);
        int count = 1;
        for(String url : allUrls) {
            driver.get(url);
            String windowsBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;     
            js.executeScript("window.open('');");
            ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
            driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(count));
            count = count + 1;
            Thread.sleep(3);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```